# Backup CentOS Webserver & install it on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, nginx

I was wondering if it was possible to make a complete backup copy of a CentOS Web-server and install it on a local machine.

I am new to Ruby on Rails and find it difficult to program without erroring out the complete server. so i would like to make a seperate server that i can use for development porposes

```
Godaddy.com VPS ultimate server CentOS 6.4
ruby 1.9.3
RoR 3
Nginx
Postgras SQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test a server, using it's own operating system etc, on your own local machine, you should look into Vagrant. http://www.vagrantup.com/

There's a lot to learn, and to be honest, while you're learning, you may want to consider an easier option for deployment, such as https://www.heroku.com/ or https://ninefold.com/ and then worry about figuring out how to set up a server by yourself once you're more experienced.

If those options are too expensive, you could consider https://www.digitalocean.com/ - you can create / destroy servers easily, and if you pick their pre-built ruby on rails server (under applications tab, when you get to that step), you'll save yourself some pain.

Lastly, if you decide you really want to learn how to set up a server for rails, you should look at this book: https://leanpub.com/deploying_rails_applications

You'll save yourself a lot of time and frustration by learning it all once, properly and thoroughly, than by learning it ad-hoc by solving error after error.

But again, if you're new to rails, I'd really recommend something like Heroku to take ther server setup off your hands and let you focus on learning rails itself.